# How to solve a problem in parsing the query?

Tags: datagridview, sqlconnection

I'm using SQL light compact 4. A part of my project is to save all the information in dataGridView into a database. I have used a button for saving those data. The code for button is as follows:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\DataGridView\PMinfo.sdf";
        SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = connection;


        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT into [PMinfo] (Number, CostCenter, pType, ServiceType, Receiver, WorkCenter, Start, End, Remaining, Status, ReceiveDate) values(@Number, @CostCenter, @pType, @ServiceType, @Receiver, @WorkCenter, @Start, @End, @Remaining, @Status, @ReceiveDate)";
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostCenter", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pType", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceType", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Receiver", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkCenter", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remaining", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReceiveDate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

            connection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

But the compiler gives the following error:
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: `'There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 92,Token in error = End ]'`
Note that I don't use DataTable. I put my information directly into the DataGridView.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: There are a couple of issues you may have here. For starters, if you look at each of the parameterized `AddWithValue` commands… `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value` … this SAME cell i.e.… `Cells[0]` is used for ALL the values. This can not be right. In other words, for each row in the grid, the code is going to use the SAME value from “Cell[0]” for the Number, CostCenter, pType, ServiceType… etc… I would think those would be “different” cells for each of the parameters, something like Cell[0] for Number, Cell[1] for CostCenter, Cell[2] for pType… etc…

Comment: Also, you need to be aware that when you use the line of code… `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value` … this is going to return an `OBJECT`. Which may cause problems because the DB command “add with value” is NOT going to CONVERT that “OBJECT” to the “type” it needs. Example, on the first `Number` parameter, IF that `Number` column in the DB is an `int` or numeric type, then it will NOT know how to CONVERT that “OBJECT” to a “numeric” value. Your code needs to “convert” the OBJECTS from each cell `Value` to the proper type.

Comment: In this case you need to convert the OBJECT returned from `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value` to a “numeric” value, then use THAT numeric value as the parameter. The same will apply to ALL the parameters. If it is a `string` value, then you could use… `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()`. Point being… Whatever “type” the DB uses for that column in the DB is the same “type” your code needs to use in the parameters.

Comment: @JohnG I did all your recommendations, but the problem exists yet. The error mentioned above is in `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: You really have column named `End`? Put it into square brackets - `[End]`

Comment: @Arvo, yeah, solved. Why do we need to put square bracket for end in sql codes?

Comment: `End` is reserved keyword for SQL server.